# Check string of TextBox.Text does not contain in a string list

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a Textbox. When i will put any string in textbox, i need to check with below strings. These below strings will come from Database:
`string stringList = "\"" + string.Join("\",\"", fetchedString) + "\"";`
Output Example: "ABCD1234","EFGH5678","IJKL9101" (These are not fixed strings).
Please help me how will TextBox.Text string will be checked or compared with string list?

Comment: Why build `stringList` as a delimited string? If you need to determine whether the text that a user has entered into a textbox matches one of several possible strings, I would think something like an `ISet<string>` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve? Please post an example of some code or what you have tried already.

As it stands, you can get the contents of the text box as a string with the following

```
TextBox.Text.ToString()
```

And you should split up stringList into seperate strings using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) so that you can iterate through them to compare against your TextBox.

Comment: I have cleared my requirement, please check now. I just want to know how TextBox strings will be checked with other some strings. here these strings will be put in declared string named 'stringList'.

Comment: For your requirements, you will need to split the stringList into seperate string using String.Split. Then you can write a condition as per @Arvindraja's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```
bool isContain;
foreach (var item in stringList)
{
    if (TextBox.Text == item.ToString())
    {
        isContain = true;
        break; //using break depend on your requirement
    }
    else
    {
      //Not contain
    }
}
```

Comment: if true,then label will show "Matched"  else label will show "Not Matched". i have put your code, but showing all time "Not Matched". Please help.

Comment: `TextBox.Text` should have total value of `stringList` than only it will match. Not 1 or 2 characters.

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong here. First, the OP was asking how to determine whether `stringList` contains the textbox text; your code is doing the reverse, checking whether the textbox test contains the entire `stringList`. Second, `stringList` contains delimiters for the values that compose the list, and you'd need to use those to determine whether the textbox text matches a complete entry in `stringList` rather than a substring.

Comment: @Arvindraja, not clear about "should have total value of 'stringList' ". TextBox will hold one text and string list will come from database by below code         { string featch_Olddata = Ds_OLDData_check.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();   string[] str = featch_Olddata.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string stringList = "\"" + string.Join("\",\"", str ) + "\""; }. Please understand that TextBox.Text will be compared with "stringList". Please help.

Comment: You mean string is List not string?

Comment: You can consider it as list. In database, strings are available  ABCD1234|ASDF1234|MNBV1234, from database it will be converted "ABCD1234,ASDF1234,MNBV1234". Suppose TextBox data is "LKJH1234". It will be compared with "ABCD1234,ASDF1234,MNBV1234".

Answer (score 0):

You could store your strings in a list and then use Linq to check if they exist already.

```
var match = listOfStrings.Any(i => i.Equals(Textbox.Text))) ? "Matched" : "Not Matched";
```